# What are register_globals in PHP?

Tags: php

Can someone give some examples of what `register_globals` are?
And is `global $user_id;` considered a register global?

Comment: In a nutshell - its highly insecure and deprecated as of PHP 5.3.0.

Comment: @Russell Dias What is insecure?

Answer (score 115):

**The `register_globals` directive:**

`register_globals` is an internal PHP setting which registers the `$_REQUEST` array's elements as variables. If you submit a value in a form, via `POST` or `GET`, the value of that input will automatically be accessible via variable in the PHP script, named after the name of the input field.

In other words, if you submitted a form containing a `username` text field, the expression `($username === $_POST['username'])` at the very beginning of the script would return `true`.

Its notoriety is attributed to the fact that it opens lots of security holes, especially for people that follow anything less than a strict coding style from a security perspective.

Classic example:

```
if(user_is_admin($user))
{
    $authorized = true;
}

if($authorized)
{
    // let them do anything they want
}
```

Now, if you visited that script in a web browser and the server had `register_globals` on, you could simply append `?authorized=1` to the URL and god-mode would be enabled!

**The `global` keyword:**

`global` is a keyword has little to do with register_globals.

Here is an example of its use:

```
$foo = 'bar';

baz();

function baz()
{
    echo $foo; // PHP warns you about trying to use an uninitialized variable
               // and nothing is output (because $foo doesn't exist here)
}

buzz();

function buzz()
{
    global $foo; // Enables the use of $foo in this scope

    echo $foo; // Prints 'bar' to screen
}
```

Comment: Update 10/2013: Register_globals has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0 so it should be turned off. http://ar2.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.register-globals

Answer (score 24):

Everyone mentioning `GET`, `POST`, `REQUEST`, `COOKIE` has effect on `register_globals=on`.

I'm just writing this to let you know that -

**`$_SESSION` will be affected aswell because of `register_globals=on`.**
http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php

That means - if you do as following -

```
$_SESSION[x] = 123;
$x = 'asd';
echo $_SESSION[x];
```

The output will be `asd`.

And this will cause serious security issues and bugs. I have experienced such a bad thing recently during using Hostgator shared hosting. By Default they have `register_globals=on`.

Comment: This answer is better than Tim's, but it still doesn't explain why $PHP_SELF is only set with register_globals on.

Comment: @AndreKR because it was not asked?

Comment: @AloisMahdal I wrote this comment quite some time ago, but rereading the answer, I can see that it says that everyone mentions "GET, POST, REQUEST, COOKIE" and adds "SESSION", kind of giving the impression it would now be a complete answer, but still fails to mention $PHP_SELF.

Comment: @AndreKR I fail to see how it makes sense to evaluate "completeness" of answer based on something that *was not part of question at all*. ;-)

Comment: you mean `$_SESSION['x']` instead of `$_SESSION[x]` , i cant undrestand why the link are broken

Answer (score 18):

When you have register_globals=on, anything passed via GET or POST or COOKIE automatically appears to be global variable in code, this might have security consequences.

I.e. you click on url test.php?access_level=100 and you'll have $access_level = 100 in PHP.

When you do global $somevar - you are making your own global variable, which usually is not a big issue.

Comment: If your turn off register_globals what are GET POST, COOKIE and REQUEST equivalents?

Comment: @sadder - Take a look at: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.php - You basically use `$_GET[]` and `$_POST[]` which are superglobals. Which is quite different than register_globals.

Comment: @Peter Ajtai this confused me even more.

Comment: @sadder - Yes. It is a little confusing. But, if you read through the manual page for predefined variables (the one I linked to), making sure to look at all the examples, things should slowly clear up.

Comment: If you disable register_globals, $_GET[] would still be here.

Answer (score 11):

The register_globals setting controls how you access form, server, and environment. variables.

### register_globals=On :

You can access form attribute without Global Arrays ( GET[], POST[] & REQUEST[] )

**example:** http://www.example.com/one.php?myinput=abc

You can access directly in one.php

```
echo $myinput; // abc
```

### register_globals=Off :

You have to access all attributes only by Global Arrays.

**example:** http://www.example.com/one.php?myinput=abc

You have to access in one.php

```
echo $_GET['myinput']; //abc
```

Answer (score 8):

As I understand it, if you have register globals turned ON, then anything passed in a GET or POST gets automatically translated into a variable in PHP.

for example:

```
http://www.domain.com/vars.php?myvar=123
```

without any further coding this would automatically get turned into a variable available to the rest of your php code

```
$myvar  //with a value of 123
```

With registered globals OFF, data passed in via GET or POST is NOT automatically translated into a variable, rather, you need to request it using the Superglobals $_GET, $_POST, and $_REQUEST, etc.

http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php provides some further information as to the security implications of this.

Others can feel free to correct me if I'm wrong.

### edit:

in relation to your question re `global $user_id;`, this does not create a 'global' in the sense of 'register_globals'.  It simply alters the scope of a variable within the PHP code.

For information re scope, see: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Answer (score 4):

Global variables in php are variables that are always accessible. They are also known as superglobals. They are built in variables that are always available regardless of the scope.

There are nine superglobal variables in PHP. Some of these are relevant to this discussion.

1. `$_REQUEST`
2. `$_POST`
3. `$_GET`
4. `$_COOKIE`

Now, let's focus on the `$_REQUEST` superglobal. It is used to collect data after submitting an HTML form by user using the `POST` method.

`$_POST` and `$_REQUEST` could be used loosely interchangeably. But `$_REQUEST` also contains `$_GET` and `$_COOKIE` along with `$_POST` so you are never sure if your data came from a web form.

Now, as pointed out by @Tim `register_globals` is an internal PHP setting which registers the `$_REQUEST` array's elements as variables. It is also known as a `flag` in your php setting. It is typically set in the PHP configuration file known as `php.ini` file. This setting can have two values.

1. “on”
2. “off”.

An “on” value means that PHP will automatically create global variables for many server variables as well as query string parameters. This is not good and is a security risk.

Comment: Php `global variables` are not the same as `super global variables`. With Super globals, you don't need to use `global` keyword but you need to with normal global variables.

Answer (score 4):

Register Globals  :

> register_globals
>   The feature causes data passed to a PHP script via cookies or GET and POST requests to be made available as global variables in the script.

Default Value : "0"

Changeable : PHP_INI_PERDIR

register_globals is affected by the variables_order directive.

NOTE:

This feature has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0.

Answer (score -1):

register_globals is one of the parameters of php.ini file.The file was coming from "On" mode before PHP 5.3.8 version.If you change register_globals from Off to On, there would be some criticals about vulnerability of website.Register_globals's feature is that you can use variables without $_GET and $_POST variables.So, Any data which comes from form or URL line you can use the variable not need like $_GET or $_POST variables.Example we have this form :

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST["myinput"])){
        echo $_POST["username"];
    }?>


<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="username">
    <input type="hidden" name="myinput">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

When you submitted the form you can see your username but when you change the situation of register_globals to "On" you have not written $_POST["username"]; you can access directly to the username variable by writing this code `echo $username`