# Using a Header afects a Session Variable

Tags: php, session, header

Having serious problems with headers and session variables. Read related posts but none helped me.

I'm using sessions to store some info about the user logged in e.g. name, user_id, etc.

To start with, let's say `$_SESSION['user_id']=6;`.

Then let's sat I want to view someone's profile. There is a dropdown list where you select the person whose profile you want to view, then click `View`. The processing page for this looks up for the user_id of the person you selected and redirects you to the person's profile.

The code is something like this:

```
<?php session_start();
$_SESSION['user_id']=1; //this is the user_id of the person logged in..
/*......many lines of code*/
?>
<select name="user_id">
<option value="4">George Thuo</option>
<!--other many options-->
</select>
<input type="submit" name="view" value="View">
```

Then this will direct you to the processing page which looks something like this:

```
$user_id=$_POST['user_id'];
header("Location: view.php?user_id=".$user_id);
```

See that before we used the header, `$_SESSION['user_id']=1;`
But after the header is user, I don't know why but `$_SESSION['user_id']=4;(the user_id passed via the $_POST method`

Why is it changing?

Comment: Do you have `register_globals` on? See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593210/what-are-register-globals-in-php) for an explanation on what it is.

Comment: I've read it. I don't remember turning it on or off. Whats the default setting, or how do I know what it is set to?

Comment: Run `phpinfo();` and search for `register_globals`

Comment: thank you alot..the answer lies with `register_globals`. All is well now