# In php, using GET command for same parameter multiple times and php tags

Tags: php

First of all, I heard some web-servers allow you to reach parameter with $a instead of $_GET[a], this is not the case here.

Anyway, I have to reach a multiple times, so instead of doing $a = $_GET[a], I instead use $_GET[a] everytime. In single php tag as in `<?php ?>`, is that an issue, should I absolutely use variables? does it matter?

Another thing is my php file is really scrambled in my html, I wonder if does it matter with multiple gets?(should not, im just worried)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What you refer of using just `$a` instead of `$_GET['a']` (or `$_POST['a']` too) is an old feature known as [`register_globals`](http://php.net/register_globals). This feature was dangerous and leading to messy code, so it was considered deprecated in PHP 5.3 and finally removed in PHP 5.4.

Then, using `$_GET['a']` everywhere in your scripts may lead to problems, because you should **never** trust user input (all things coming from `$_GET`, `$_POST`, `$_REQUEST`, `$_COOKIE` and some from `$_FILES` or `$_SERVER`). It is recommended to do something like `$a = sanitize($_GET['a']);` (the `sanitize` function does not exist, depending on what type of value are you expecting, you should check that what you get is an integer, or a valid date, or whatever, depending on your needs). From now on you should stop referencing `$_GET['a']` and use instead the new sanitized variable you have just created `$a`. Because if you were using always `$_GET['a']`, chances are that you forget to sanitize it someplace.

Also, before sending this sanitized variable into a SQL query, you should escape it or use it inside a prepared statement to avoid [SQL injections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). Before outputting it to an html for the user to see, use [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) to avoid [XSS attacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110575/do-htmlspecialchars-and-mysql-real-escape-string-keep-my-php-code-safe-from-inje/110576#110576).

And finally, about having multiple php blocks mixed with html blocks, this is only bad for maintenance reasons, because in the long run it will be a complete mess. Try to separate the html you send the user from the php code. Try to read something about the [MVC pattern (Model-View-Controller)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) (this link is probably too complicated or maybe you don't see the utility right now for you that are just beginning with php (at least I didn't see how it was way better than mixing html with php, for all the complexity needed), but try to grasp the idea behind it) .

Answer (score 0):

> First of all, I heard some web-servers allow you to reach parameter with $a instead of $_GET[a], this is not the case here.

This is a PHP config setting called `register_globals`. It is insecure and should NOT be used. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593210/what-are-register-globals-in-php) for more information.

You can access an element in the `$_GET` array as many times as you like, it will not cause problems. However if you are printing an element of the `$_GET` array (or any other user submitted data) to the page, you should run it through `htmlspecialchars()` or the like before printing it out to prevent XSS vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 0):

using a variable is a preference for you to decide it does not matter. but variable is the way forward if you use the same one multiple times.

```
<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['a']);?>
```

using a variable means that it reusable again especially if you have added extra code, which mean just editing one variable for all instances.

```
<?php $a = htmlspecialchars($_GET['a']);

echo $a;
echo $a;
echo $a;
echo $a;

?>
```