# old php code do not work for basic parameter transfering

Tags: php

Just upgrade php, very simple sample does not work properly

test.php

```
 <?php 

 echo "$query";

 ?>
```

when I call

```
test.php?query=5
```

It should display

```
5
```

but What I got is nothing display which mean $query is ''

Your comment welcome

Comment: You have to use $_GET["query"]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using

```
$query = $_GET['query'];
```

Comment: what about the case of post/form?

Comment: $query = $_POST['query'];

Answer (score 2):

Its a new secuirty feature. It used to be called register globals.

http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php

Not you have to use the $_GET, $_POST or use $_REQUEST global variables to obtain this information.

for example your code would be

```
 <?php 

 echo $_GET['query'];

 ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your previous PHP register_globals directive was on, allowing you to use $REQUEST array's elements as global variables. That's why the code worked. This feature was deprecated in PHP 5.3.0 and removed in PHP 5.4.0: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.register-globals

Don't use it. Apply to $_GET, $_POST and $_REQUEST arrays directly.

[What are register_globals in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593210/what-are-register-globals-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

Your upgrade turned off the insecure, horrible, and smelly `register_globals`. You are better off for this, despite the work you must now do.

You will have to change every instance of

```
$query
```

to

```
$_GET['query']
```

File the time spent under "Security".

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `$_GET`

> An associative array of variables passed to the current script via the
>   URL parameters.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

```
$query = $_GET['query'];
```