# how to modify below code that require Global Session On to Global Session Off

Tags: php, mysql, session

newbie question here..
i have login code as below, with below codes would require the Session Global On to be function. The question is how to modify the codes so that it will work with the Session Global Off? pls advise..

```
<?

session_start();
if(isset($submit) )
{
include ("config.php");
include ("../dbcon.php");
include ("functions.php");;

$result=mysql_query("select * from users where login='$username'");
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);

$pasw=$row["pass"];
}
if($pasw==$password){
$HTTP_SESSION_VARS['l']=$username;
$HTTP_SESSION_VARS['p']=$password;


Header("Location: ../index.php");
exit;
}
else
header("Location: ../index.php?page=loginfailed");


?>
```

Comment: Using `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` may be a better way to check if the submit button was in fact clicked.

Comment: As a newbie you should not start with so ancient code, it will not teach you anything good. Following http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php you can see that the deprecated HTTP_SESSION_VARS is now $_SESSION

Comment: so, if use if(isset($_POST['submit'])) it will work when the Global Session set to Off?

Comment: Go through this link, you will get the solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593210/what-are-register-globals-in-php

Comment: @user2841315 Try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Use $_SESSION['variable_name'] instead of globally register HTTP_SESSION_VARS