# $_POST being automatically copied into other variables

Tags: php, lamp

(I apologize for a stupid question. This must be a simple setting, but an hour of Google hasn't revealed it.)

We have a LAMP web server. When we send data through post, the `$_POST` variable is set as expected. But we also get a global variable for every entry in `$_POST`.

For instance, if `$_POST['Research']` is "Yes", we also get a global `$Research` set to "Yes".

How do we turn this off?

Comment: Can you show us the coding segment where the $_POST array is assigned its key=>value? It may help in answering this question.

Comment: oh god you have register globals on - FLEEE: http://php.net/manual/en/faq.using.php#faq.register-globals

Comment: @Quentin I'm not setting it... it is a superglobal input to my php code.

Comment: As above, its register globals, which means you also have a pretty old php installation. You can turn it off in php.ini, but better to update to a newer php anyway (where it has been depreciated)

Comment: @Dagon That is definitely the setting. Thank you. My terrible sysadmin turned that on for no reason. If you submit an answer, I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have the dangerous and deprecated

**register globals on**

basic details:

http://php.net/manual/en/faq.using.php#faq.register-globals

to turn off:
http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.register-globals

if your php version is so old that it came with this on by default you should upgrade

Answer (score 1):

Your description sounds like you are using [register globals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593210/what-are-register-globals-in-php)?

If so I am surprised you are still able to as they are deprecated.

You should update your php or at least disable it in your php.ini conf - register_globals=0;